# Blank column in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a report in SSRS which has multiple matrix's, some longer than other. Each goes on a new sheet when exported to excel. The problem is here- on the sheets with the shorter tables, there is a long blank column at the end. Any way to get rid of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**No**. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to get rid of the extra space.

You can add blank columns so they cover up the extra space created by the missing columns in your table with fewer columns.